# AVR Port pins: read and write

Tags: microcontroller, avr

As the ports are connected to pull-up resistors; the port pin values should be at level 1 when not connected to the outside world.I wrote the below code to set the lower half of PORTA as input and the upper half as output.
As I wrote 0xFF on PORTA, i was expecting to get 0xFF with the last IN instruction. Instead, I get with the simulator 0xF0, only the output pins got updated, what about the pull-up resistors? Actually, the initial value of PINA is 0. is it a software bug?

```
LDI R16, 0xF0
OUT DDRA, R16
SER R16
OUT PORTA,R16
NOP
NOP
IN R16, PINA
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try on real hardware? I guess its a "feature" in the simulator. See https://www.avrfreaks.net/s/topic/a5C3l000000Ub9sEAC/t156628 (2nd cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Link to discussion about the same topic](https://www.avrfreaks.net/s/topic/a5C3l000000Ub9sEAC/t156628) i would say:

The pull-ups are not "used" in the simulator. Therefore, the observed behaviour is as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I don't have access to a hardware board otherwise I would have tested it.